# How can I return values with an RSpec class_double and as_stubbed_const?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, mocking

I have a class `MyVoucherClass` that calls a separate service within a Rails application.

In the class that I am testing, `VoucherIssuer`, I am calling two of `MyVoucherClass`’s class methods, `issue_voucher` and `activate_voucher` which POST to the separate service.

I want to stub the entire `MyVoucherClass` and what values its class methods return. From RSpec documentation and further searching I have found that the following should work:

```
subject(:issue_credits) { described_class.new.issue_credits }

let(:my_voucher_class_double) do
  class_double(MyVoucherClass,
               issue_voucher: { voucher_id: "ABC123" }.to_json,
               activate_voucher: instance_double(VoucherClass, voucher_id: "ABC123")
  ).as_stubbed_const
end

context “when using MyVoucherClass” do
    it “calls on MyVoucherService” do
        issue_credits
    end
end
```

However, it throws the error:

`WebMock::NetConnectNotAllowedError: Real HTTP connections are disabled. Unregistered request: POST [separate service url]`

which means that the method return value stubbing is not working.

I am working around this with multiple `allow(MyVoucherClass) ... and_return()` statements instead, but I am wondering why the class double and as_stubbed_const are not working, because it would be ideal to do it in one `class_double` instead of `allow` twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[let & let!](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let)

> Note that let is lazy-evaluated: it is not evaluated until the first time
> the method it defines is invoked. You can use let! to force the method's
> invocation before each example.

Either you can call `my_voucher_class_double` inside `it` block to invoked or use `let!` instead of `let`

- Using `let`

```
   subject(:issue_credits) { described_class.new.issue_credits }

   let(:my_voucher_class_double) do
     class_double(MyVoucherClass,
                  issue_voucher: { voucher_id: "ABC123" }.to_json,
                  activate_voucher: instance_double(VoucherClass, voucher_id: "ABC123")
     ).as_stubbed_const
   end

   context “when using MyVoucherClass” do
       it “calls on MyVoucherService” do
           my_voucher_class_double
           issue_credits
       end
   end
```

- Using `let!`

```
   subject(:issue_credits) { described_class.new.issue_credits }

   let!(:my_voucher_class_double) do
     class_double(MyVoucherClass,
                  issue_voucher: { voucher_id: "ABC123" }.to_json,
                  activate_voucher: instance_double(VoucherClass, voucher_id: "ABC123")
     ).as_stubbed_const
   end

   context “when using MyVoucherClass” do
       it “calls on MyVoucherService” do
           issue_credits
       end
   end
```

Comment: Shoot, that simple! Thank you.